# Expose compiled Julius templates as a seperate file, instead of directly placing them in the DOM

Tags: javascript, haskell, yesod

When debugging JS, Chrome allows you edit JS and then reload the page. This can only happen if the JS you are editing is provided as a separate resource. As far as I can tell, it's currently not possible to debug JS code is this fashion because of the way Yesod drops any included JS on to the page directly.

Editing a julius template file without changing any variable interpolation allows for instant reloading of the page. However, if I include small snippets of javascript with:

```
toWidget [julius|doStuff();|]
```

I can't edit this Javascript for debugging without causing a reload of the model, which for our case, takes ~1minute. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple choices here:

- If you put the Julius content in an external file, you can use `juliusFileReload` and then edit the file and reload the webpage without a recompile. The scaffolded site does this by default.
- Have generated Javascript be placed in a separate file. This is also the default behavior of the scaffolded site.

Comment: 2nd method: Seems to be exactly what I want - does this affect performance?

Comment: Yes, there are tradeoffs regarding HTTP round-trips vs enhanced content caching. It's actually a really big topic in the general web dev world.

Comment: Are there any Yesod blog posts around this topic that you know of?